# How to python delete unwanted icon characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, character, non-ascii-characters

Is there a way to get a string to get rid of **icon characters** automatically?

**input**: This is String ✅this is string✅✍️string✍️✔️
**output wish**: This is String this is stringstring

**replace('✅', '')** is not used because the icon character changes within each string without our prior knowledge of the content

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
def strip_emoji(text):
    RE_EMOJI = re.compile(u'([\U00002600-\U000027BF])|([\U0001f300-\U0001f64F])|([\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF])')
    return RE_EMOJI.sub(r'', text)

print(strip_emoji('This is String ✅this is string✅✍️string✍️✔️'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `re` module in Python to replace characters that you don't want. Something like:

```
import re

re.sub(r'[^(a-z|A-Z)]', '', my_string)
```